# How to limit the text appearing inside a label content

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to limit the text length inside a label (the 'content') in a way that I would be able to enter text and after reaching the limit the text is still typing but the shown text is only the allowed length, then if I want to see the whole text I'll need to locate the mouse right above the label to see all of the written text inside a tool tip.

The only solution I could find is the "MaxWidth" property.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot type in a `Label` though.

Comment: OK, sorry, I need to be more specific: I'm binding the label content to some text box which has no limit but I want to limit the label's content length in a way that the program still write the text, I will see only the allowed length and I would be able to see all of the text while mouse hovering the label..

Comment: What have you tried so far - if you show your code we can better help you.

Comment: Set maxWifth and make Tooltip= bidning Text, relativeSource self

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would limit amount of text by available size, not length. Size depends on layout.

I'd use `TextBlock` to display text entered into `TextBox` instead of `Label`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=someTextBox}"
           ToolTip="{Binding Text, ElementName=someTextBox}"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! thanks! that works like a magic :)